# How to run .exe on windows startup without having admin access?

Tags: passwords, administration

I want to know how to bypass the requirement of an admin user in order to have a program run upon windows startup.

Comment: There are many ways to reach your attempt such as modify registry adding a startup key specifying an exe or the simplest way is to add your executable in startup directory, should be located in C:\Users\[User Name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup. Often are used both methods. You can also inject your process in another one which already automatically is opened at startup. As I said there are many methods to make this one. Your question is too vague to get a precise answer.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing a non-admin can do will modify the OS boot process, unless the user has physical access to the machine and the ability to modify the boot disk offline. That situation pretty strictly supersedes Administrator access, but can be blocked by Bitlocker or other full-volume encryption (where TPM is used and you don't have the key), especially if Secure Boot is also enabled and can't be disabled.

Think about it: what you're asking for (change how the OS works, without being authorized to do that) amounts to "I want to break the most visible security feature of the most widely used desktop operating system on the planet". Even if anybody here has a way to do that, they're not going to tell you, not when they could get a big pile of cash for either telling MSFT about it, selling it on the black market, or using it to create malware themselves.

Now, if you're asking for a way to run a program ***when you log in***, that's not hard at all. there's the per-user Startup folder in the Start menu (`%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`), the per-user Run key in the Registry (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`), create a scheduled task that runs when you log in (`taskschd.msc` or `schtasks.exe`), and probably other options. However, these approaches will only execute your program when *you* log in (they won't run pre-login, or when somebody else logs in), and only under your own privileges (they won't run as SYSTEM, Administrator, or as any other user).

To be clear, each of those approaches *could* be used to do things for other users at login, and some can do things before login, but you need Admin to make any changes that would affect other users or pre-login behavior.

Obviously, this won't let you see user passwords or perform system administration (things I assume you're interested in, based on the tags you added), though.

Comment: Admin access is needed to add something to my user startup folder. Google brought me here while searching for how to autostart an application when my user session starts.

Comment: @Ocean No, it's definitely not. You're either trying to add something to _all user's_ startup folder, _another user's_ startup folder, or somebody has restricted your permissions (e.g. with nannyware) or reduced your access to the folder. By default, the Startup folder is owned by the user whose account it's in, and the owner has Full Control of the folder (all access permissions). There is nothing in the ACL that would stop you from adding, changing, or removing anything in your own Startup folder.

Comment: I copy pasted "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" and that folder needs admin access, which I do not have. The default setup might be different and nice, but I have to deal with what I've got.

Comment: @Ocean That sounds like something that could be its own question - probably on Superuser, not Security.SE - as to what in the world is going on. Post a screenshot of the ACL on that folder if you do. My best guess is the "somebody else messed with your system" (which I presume did happen, since you're apparently not admin on it, but restricting Startup is so very weird), though there's an outside chance that your environment variable is wrong (did it expand to a path with your username in it?). In any case, if you can't fix the ACL on Startup, you can still try the registry or scheduled task.